# Android -How to request audio focus of voice call stream

Tags: android, audio, streaming, android-audiomanager

How do i request and gain the audio focus of the voice call stream in Android?  When i do the below code for the music stream it work fine and i gain the focus but for STREAM_VOICE_CALL the framework does not grant it:

```
// this works
     AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

         int result=  am.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);


---------
```

// this is not granted:

```
      AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

         int result=  am.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

Can someone confirm is the OS has access to the voice call audio stream in jelly bean and up ?